# Where can I buy the 2005 Mazda 3s 2.3L oxygen sensor plug?

Tags: engine, o2-sensor

I bought an oxygen sensor with the wrong plug. I wonder were could I buy a plug like the one on my car in order to connect the oxygen sensor properly?

This is an image of the plug on my car.
[image: This is an image of the plug on my car]

Does anyone know what kind of pug is this or where could I buy it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Buy the correct O2 sensor, hacking up the OEM harness to put a different O2 sensor on the car is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have bought the wrong oxygen sensor, the correct sensor will have the correct plug on it. The easiest solution is to take it back where you got it from and have it replaced for the correct one. In an emergency situation you could cut the plug off the old sensor, leaving a couple off inches of the wires, cut the plug off of the new sensor. Then wire the new sensor and old plug wire for wire together. Not recommended.